# Search values in string with separator

Tags: python

The following code will search for val1. How to find val2?

```
x = "[val1][val2]"
section = x[x.find("[")+1:x.find("]")]
print(section)

>> val1
```

How find val2 ? eg. return to array section[0] and section[1]

edited.

Comment: show your desired output? and explain it what are you trying to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
x = "[val1][val2]"
values = x[1:-1].split("][")
print(values)
```

1. `x[1:-1]` removes the two `[]` characters on each end (`"[val1][val2]"` -> `"val1][val2"`)
2. `.split("][")` splits the string into a list of two (`"val1][val2"` -> `["val1", "val2"]`
3. `print(values)` print out the values!

Hope this helps explain this code!

**NOTE:** This works for any number of values (try `"[val1][val2][val3]"`)!

Comment: I don't know how much val will be ... Sometimes one [val] sometimes several [val1] [val2] [val3] ...

Comment: This code actually works for any number of values... Let me add that to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use `re` to list all the strings that are between two square brackets, non-greedy:

```
import re
x = "[val1][val2]" 
section = re.findall('(?<=\[).*?(?=\])',x)
print(section)
```

Output:

```
['val1', 'val2']
```

Comment: @AyushGarg Thanks!

Comment: Also, OP says that they can't use regex or any other libraries :/

Answer (score 0):

```
x = "[val1][val2]"

section = x.replace('[',' ').replace(']',' ').split()
print(section[0], section[1])
```

Prints:

```
val1 val2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
def extract(inp):
    tmp=inp
    while len(tmp):
        start=tmp.find('[')
        end=tmp.find(']')
        if start==-1 or end==-1:
            break
        val=tmp[start+1:end]
        yield val
        tmp=tmp[end+1:]
    
x = "[val1][val2]"
for i in extract(x):
    print(i)
```